# 'sort' produces output in a weird order

Tags: sort, coreutils

Consider the following input to sort:

```
cat > foo <<EOM
D,,5014978
DD,,25
D,I,1972765530
D,Y,4223624
-,Y,71285059
YA,I,2
EOM
```

Now try running `sort foo`.

The output is not sorted when trying this on any of my Linux boxes (GNU coreutils versions 6.9-8.26). I get this instead:

```
$ sort foo
D,,5014978
DD,,25
D,I,1972765530
D,Y,4223624
-,Y,71285059
YA,I,2
```

Obviously, all the lines with `D,` should be together, and `-` should come before any letters.

The output is sorted when run under Cygwin (GNU coreutils 8.5).  Comments?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sorting depends on the locale; specifically, it depends on `$LC_COLLATE` (possibly overridden by `$LC_ALL`), falling back to `$LANG` if it doesn't exist.  The command `locale` will show you what values you're effectively working with.  See [`man 3 strcoll`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcoll.html), [`man 3 setlocale`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setlocale.html), etc.

`LC_COLLATE=C` (or `POSIX` or no locale at all) results in a strict byte-by-byte comparison.

`LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8` results in an alphabetical-equivalence sort, with punctuation ignored and characters within the same equivalence class treated equally.

Comment: Indeed, `export LC_COLLATE=C` makes sort behave as expected

Comment: Accents are not completely ignored. `Stephane` sorts _before_ `Stéphane`, but `Stephanie` sorts after `Stéphane`. `é` is equivalent to `e` (like `ê`, `ë`, `ẽ`...), but if there's a tie, then the order between those is well defined. It's the same in a good old paper dictionary.

Comment: If you really want to know it all: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/